# What is session invalidation?

Tags: servlets

Session invalidation means session destroying.So if session is destroyed,it indicates that server cant identify the client which has visited in previous.So now it creates a new session id for that client.

Is this right?If wrong tell me the correct procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Calling HttpSession.invalidate() simply clears any object that is bound to it and marks it as invalid, so if you try to modify it afterward it will throw exceptions.

Once a session has been invalidated, the SessionID placed in a cookie on the client will be invalid too, and a new one will have to be created when a new session object is created. So the new Session will have a new ID.

This is usefull to handle for example login/logout. Sessions should always be invalidated at login to help prevent Session fixation attacks

Comment: what happens the data corresponding to that invalidated session id

Comment: nothing special, since the session is destroyed its not accessible from the session anymore. If the session was the only object keeping references to it, it is eligible for garbage collection

Comment: so you mean to say - once anyhow - my session is invalidated I can not - handle that invalidation through exception handling and show my user with proper page ?

Answer (score 1):

`Yes, absolutely right`. Invalidating a session will mark the session as invalid and will be destroyed. If the client comes with the session id which has been invalidated a new session will be created.

Comment: what happens to the session variable when we exit the browser?

Comment: Sever will invalidate them after certain idle timeout value. You can also configure the session-timeout value in web.xml.

Comment: what happend for all attribute i have set session.setAttribute do they become cleared or something ; or it does not have to do with the subject here means they will remain

Answer (score 1):

**session.inValidate():**

If we are logging into gmail then at server side server will create session object

If we are calling session.inValidate() method means we are logged out since session object is destroyed by the server.